# make a regex that matches a string which comprises a url and image extensions

Tags: php, regex

I am bad at regex, having said that, I am trying to make a regex that will allow all the picture types of a url something like this:

```
$regex = '~mydomain.ide.com/polopoly_fs/([a-z0-9\\.\\_\\-]+(\\.gif|\\.png|\\.jpe?g))~i';
```

//include all formats

The purpose is to get a web's pictures with a function that could be like this:

```
/**
 * Get the Images
 * @param unknown $html
 */
function getImages($html) {
  echo "Hello from getImages <br/>";

  $matches = array();

  $regex = '~http://mySite.ide.com/([a-z0-9\\.\\_\\-]+(\\.gif|\\.png|\\.jpe?g))~i'; //include all formats

  preg_match_all($regex2, $html, $matches);
  foreach ($matches[1] as $img) {
    saveImg($img);
  }
}
```

But I need a regex which does it with a url with this structure:

http://mydomain.ide.com/polopoly_fs/1.573651!imageManager/3188890795.jpg

Can anybody help?

Thank you

Comment: What are you using it for? Maybe there is a better way than using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should suffice.

```
/(.*.com\/[a-z_-]+\/[0-9\.a-z!]+\/[a-z0-9_-]+\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png))/i
```

Here's the PHP code

```
<?php

$s = "http://mydomain.ide.com/polopoly_fs/1.573651!imageManager/3188890795.jpg";

preg_match("/(.*.com\/[a-z_-]+\/[0-9\.a-z!]+\/[a-z0-9_-]+\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png))/i", $s, $arrMatches);

echo print_r($arrMatches[0], true);
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/198050)

- Case insensitive match
- Will only match `.com` tld, but can be adapted to match more

Answer (score 1):

Ok now that's a little more clear I can help a little more.

If I understand properly what you want is to search a whole html for images urls fully qualified to save them, no care of the name or where they are at all.

```
function getImages($html) {
  echo "Hello from getImages <br/>";

  $matches = array();

  $regex = '~http://.*/[a-z0-9._-]+(?:\.gif|\.png|\.jpe?g)~i'; //include all formats

  preg_match_all($regex, $html, $matches);
  foreach ($matches as $img) {
    saveImg($img[0]);
  }
}
```

you don't have to capture anything here, the match will be enought, the only char needing to be escaped is the . to match a  littelal dot in .gif .png , etc.

If I misunderstood, feel free to comment and I'll adapt